# Can dummy True/False be in the consequent side of the implication and what it could mean?

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, artificial-intelligence, sequent-calculus

It is known that `False -> SomeFact` is the use of the implication for the representation of the facts in the propositional and first order logic. The Sequent (of the sequence calculus) is the implication whose antecedant is some conjunction of formulas and whose consequent is some disjunction of formulas. The sequent format requires that something should be in the antecedant and in the consequent (those sets of formulas can not be empty - as I understand) and my question is: can `True` exclusively-or `False` be the only members of the consequent of the implication and what such implications mean?

My question is connected to my other question:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118588/can-full-first-order-knowledge-base-be-written-as-the-single-sequent-in-the-sequ
which asks whether single sequent can represent entire knowledge base? Knowledga base, as we know, is the set for formulas, i.e. the long conjunction of the formulas, can any such conjunction be converted to the implication, i.e. to the sequent?

Comment: If $\top$ is „true“ and $\bot$ is „false“ and $A,B$ are two statements then we have $$\neg A\equiv A\implies\top$$ and $$A\lor B\equiv (\neg A)\implies B$$ so I suppose the answer is yes (??)

Comment: Your question "can True exclusively-or False be the only members of the consequent of the implication and what such implications mean?" is not clear at all. What do you mean? Moreover, why in the title do you mention the antecedent and not the consequent?

Comment: I am just confused (and I provided context) - I am reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01467.pdf and I have idea to use sequent calculus for the knowledge representation and reasoning (i.e. as knowledge base), but knowledge base if big conjunction but sequent format required the implication format and I am just trying to do conversion among those formats.

Comment: Besides, some sequent rules (e.g. for AND and implication) creates 2 sequents from the one sequent (creates 2 proof obligations). If I am applying such sequent rule for my initial sequent (initial KB) then what such branching means for my KB? Does is mean, that my KB is being split into two KBs?

Comment: @TomR I think we're missing some context here - can you say a bit about what a knowledge base is/does that is relevant to you?

Comment: To your specific question though: your claim "The sequent format requires that something should be in the antecedant and in the consequent (those sets of formulas can not be empty)" is incorrect. For example, "$\perp\vdash$" and "$\vdash\top$" are both correct sequents; "$\top\vdash$" is an incorrect sequent, but is still "grammatically well-formed."

Comment: I guess in your question there is a misunderstanding. Don't confuse the symbol $\Rightarrow$ (or $\vdash$) that separates antecedent and consequent in a sequent (and is part of the meta-language), with the symbol $\to$ for the implication in the object language.

Comment: I guess that domain is irrelevant here, but if asked - it will be commonsense knowledge base for the Artificial General Intelligence. I am trying to use Grammatical Framework and formal semantics of natural language to convert natural language texts (e.g. laws) into FOL or HOL sentences and form knowledge base. Then I would like to make deductions in this set of formulas and I feel that sequent calculus can be good tool for making deductions. But it requires to represent all the KB as one sequent and then there is brancing.

Comment: But chapter 2.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01467.pdf clearly states that double-line arrow is just replacement for the implication (one-line arrow). At least in the case when the sequents are used for the proof of validity. Maybe sequents can be used for only that?

Comment: Well, my mention of AGI went bad. Another application of my efforts can be: I can try to use Grammatical Framework to convert mathematical natural language texts into formal expressions (FOL, HOL formulas) and then establish reasoning procedures (templates of applications of sequent rules) that convert such sets of expressions into formal proofs that can be deposited into https://www.isa-afp.org/ and in such a way extend the domain of formalized and automated mathematics - and do it automatically (as manual work is so hard and expensive).

Comment: " it requires to represent all the KB as one sequent" Why not as a *collection of* sequents? That seems much more natural to me.

Comment: And re: empty sets of formulas, the very text you quote states "Note that validity of finite sequents does indeed
generalise validity of formulas since the formula $\varphi$ is valid iff the sequent $\emptyset\implies \varphi$ is valid." The antecedent/consequent sets are never assumed to be nonempty!

Comment: But what is the collection of sequents? Isn't it just conjunction of implications (sequents as implications)?

Comment: @TomR I'm not sure what you're asking at this point, to be honest. Let's ignore the KB issue and just focus on this particular question: do you understand the example in the cited text about $\emptyset\implies\varphi$?

Comment: At this point I have to have a rest (it is late night at this part of the world) and be ready for the next day, I definitely continue thinking about this tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual presentation of sequent calculus [see e.g. Gaisi Takeuti, [Proof Theory (1987)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&printsec=frontcover), page 8] :

> $\Gamma, \Delta$ denote finite (possibly empty) sequences of formulas [...].
>
> **Def.1.8** For arbitrary $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ in the above notation, $\Gamma \to \Delta$ is called a *sequent*.
>
> A sequent of the form $A \to A$ is called an *initial sequent* or *axiom*.

If we have the $\bot$ symbol in the language, the following sequent is an axiom : $\bot \to \bot$.

Thus, using $\supset \text {-right}$ [I'll use $\supset$ for the conditional, having used $\to$ for the sequent] we immediately conclude with :

> $\to \bot \supset \bot$

that can be read as $\to \lnot \bot$, i.e. as $\to \top$.

What is the meaning of the sequent : $\to \bot$ ?

We have that [see page 11] a formula $\varphi$ is provable (in the calculus) if the sequent $\to \varphi$ is provable. From the semantical point of view, by soundness, this means that $\varphi$ is a *valid* formula.

Thus, to derive the sequent $\to \bot$ amounts to a proof that the calculus is *inconsistent*.

---

If the logic does not include $\bot$, we have that [see page 9] the empty sequent $\to$ means that there is a contradiction.

Thus, the definition of *inconsistent* is the following [see page 21] :

> A system $\mathscr A$ [a finite or infinite set of sentences, called the axioms of the system, that means adding to the calculus the initial sequents : $\to A$, for every $A$ in $\mathscr A$] is *inconsistent* if the empty sequent : $\to$ is provable from $\mathscr A$.

---

---

As discussed in some [previous thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441350/can-sequent-calculus-start-with-facts-and-assert-facts-i-e-can-sequent-calculu), the "application" of sequent calculus to some "topic" needs an initial set of non-logical axioms : specific mathematical axioms for e.g. a mathematical theory or specific "facts" related to a knowledge base.

These axioms must be expressed as initial sequents of the form $\to \text {Ax}$.